# Insights Graph API- Follower_count return showing 2 days outdated

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

We are using: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights

Trying to return:

follower_count

day

Total number of new followers each day within the specified range. Returns a maximum of 30 days worth of data. Not available on IG Users with fewer than 100 followers.

However, follower_count is returning data that is 2 days old and not up to date, as others are returning up to date data. Any idea on this